# suitescript - could not get value from search result

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

[![

This data has been loaded from calling saved search.

Cannot access only the value of NDC and prod_desc. But the others are accessible?  ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ucK.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ucK.png)

[image]

Comment: Try spitting out the searchresult variable to show everything that is in it, to ensure that there is actually data there.  It's possibly that that column is a join or a summary, in which case you'll have to alter the way you get the value from it.  Alternatively, you can use columns IDs to grab the data, instead of string names.

Comment: It is impossible to know what the issue is without seeing all the details of the search. Pull up the saved search in the UI and use the Chrome addon NetSuite: Search Export to easily convert the search to code. Edit your question and paste the search criteria in there. With that info we can point you in the right direction (although, once converted to code, you may yourself discover what is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not transaction fields.
If you have the item's purchase description and item id in the search results then you'd access those in script using the join syntax:

```
var ndc = searchResult.getValue('itemid', 'item');
var prod_desc = searchResult.getValue('purchasedescription', 'item');
```